# Compiling a Matlab code with a VLfeat library in java

Tags: java, matlab, vlfeat

I'm having trouble compiling my Matlab code in java (with the matlab compiler tool) because I use **VLfeat** inside my code. This is the error it generates:

```
Error using loadlibrary (line 447)
There was an error loading the library "vlfeat\toolbox\vl_setup"
Undefined function or variable 'vl_setup_proto'.
Error in sift_uniform_grid (line 7)
Error in sift_bag_of_words (line 25)
```

Do you have any ideas of how to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

It might not be properly set up and Matlab does not include vlfeat in the created jar, or cant see it. Try to add vlfeat directory to shared resources and helper files or check vlfeat path.